# A jar has 20 candies, with 4 of each of the following flavors: cherry, lemon, lime, orange, & grape. Find ways of choosing 8 candies given constraint

Tags: combinatorics

Question:

A jar contains 20 candies, with 4 of each of the following flavors: cherry, lemon, lime,
orange, and grape. How many ways can you choose 8 candies such that you have at least
one of each flavor?

**My attempt -**

To choose 8 candies such that you have at least one of each flavor, I first choose one candy of each flavor. This leaves me with the need to choose an additional 3 candies from the 20 - 5 = 15 remaining candies (since I already have one of each flavor).

The problem, therefore, breaks down into two parts:

1.Choose 1 candy of each flavor.

2.Choose 3 additional candies without restriction.

For the first part, there's really only 1 way to do this, since I'm choosing one of each flavor.

For the second part, I can choose 3 additional candies from the 15 remaining without restriction. So 15C3 or 455 ways to choose the additional 3 candies.

Is my approach correct?

Thanks

Comment: It's better to split your ways of choosing the 3 remaining candies into 3 cases:

1) the candies are all of the same type

2) the candies are all distinct types

3) the candies are 2 of one type, and 1 of another.

and handle the cases separately. 
Otherwise, you risk over-counting.

Comment: Note that if you want this count  for a probability of having at least one of each flavor, the "ways" are not equally probable.

Comment: If candies of the same flavor are considered to be indistinguishable, your answer to the second step is way too large.  If candies of the same flavor are considered distinct, your answer to the first step is too small.  I would interpret the question to mean that candies of the same flavor are considered to be indistinguishable.